# How do I downgrade from 18.10 to 18.04

Tags: downgrade

I recently upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10... Wanting to revert to LTS. Can I do this without re-installing Ubuntu?

Comment: No, you can't. But you can do the next "best" thing which is reusing the same partitions but do not format `/`. This will keep your user files and settings.

Comment: Thanks, I did this last night on another machine, it really wasn't that bad. :)